# COII: Which OpenCV functions secretly change COI?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, parallel.foreach

I'm using OpenCV (in C# through Emgu). When I run my (~10k lines) code with MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1, everything's great. When I run truly in parallel, I get an OpenCV Exception that Convolution (and a few other functions) don't support COI.

Apparently, something's changing an Image[Gray,byte]'s COI to 1, doing some work, and then changing it back to 0. In serial, that's fine. In parallel, it breaks other OpenCV functions that crash when COI≠0. I didn't even know about COI until today, so it must be some prebuilt function in OpenCV. (Like how img.Copy subtly uses img.ROI.)

I replaced every local "img.Method(" with "img.SafeMethod(", where I wrote the Safe one to check COI, lock img, do actual Method, unlock img, and check COI again. I replaced tons of { .CountNonzero, .Copy, .Or, .Not, .Threshold, .Sub, .And, . Convolution, .Xor }. It still breaks (only in parallel).

I clearly missed an img.Method somewhere, since someone's changing an img.COI (while ignoring the img lock). Any idea which OpenCV methods change COI back and forth, so I can lock while they work?

Edit: More info on COI https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvcreateimage#void%20cvSetImageCOI(IplImage*%20image,%20int%20coi)

and my exception. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d0d/namespacecv_1_1Error.html#a759fa1af92f7aa7377c76ffb142abccaa76945d22fdcd44f361e444bc59a8337f